# 18.04 only works in recovery mode

Tags: data-recovery, 18.04, mode

I upgraded from 17.10 to 18.04 following the prompts and instructions from Software Updater. Everything went smoothly.
I could see the background image had changed form the Aadvark to the Beaver, and got the "restart" message.
When I hit restart, the familiar Ubuntu purple background and white / red dots appeared but then, instead of opening the OS, I got a page with lots of scrolling text, and eventually it froze. 
tried rebooting several times: same result. So i went for recovery mode, and it opened ok, but it ìs obviously only recovery mode and I can't get the real thing to work.
Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: go to recovery mode, open a terminal and run command: `sudo grep -Pi "(critical|err|fail|fatal)" /var/log/syslog /var/log/syslog.1 /var/log/boot.log`. Add the output to your question (as text).

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean by "add the output to you question (as text)?

Comment: Edit your question and copy paste the output of that command to your question. And click the Code button `{}` to make it look nice.

Comment: OK, I know what you mean now

Comment: The trouble is the output is absolutely MASSIVE. Can't paste it here. How about a word document, can I send / attach that?

Comment: When i pasted output onto a word document it's actually 154 pages long!

Comment: wow. Okay first of all leave the syslog and only add the boot.log output only

Comment: morgan@morgan-MacBookAir:~$ sudo grep -Pi "(critical|err|fail|fatal)" /var/log/boot.log
[sudo] password for morgan: 
[FAILED] Failed to start AppArmor initialization.
[FAILED] Failed to start AppArmor initialization.

Comment: Oh dear, looks like no one can help! Shame . . .

Comment: @CoMo Unfortunately, _you_ failed to do what RoVo requsted, particularly to [edit] your question. It helps to keep our Q&A style tidy and could also bring more attention since an edited question gets bounced on the homepage.